# Build.scala: specify scala version does not work

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, salat

I use playframework and here is my appDependencies in Build.scala:

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
jdbc,
anorm,
"com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.0.1",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-agent" % "2.1.0",
"org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.5.0",
"com.novus" % "salat_2.9.1" % "1.9.1",
"se.radley" % "play-plugins-salat_2.9.1" % "1.1"
```

)

There are no salat and play-salat plugins for scala 2.10 so I specify scala version explicitly. But it takes no effect:

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/johndoe/projects/myproject/}myproject...
[warn]  module not found: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1                              
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/johndoe/projects/lib/play/repository/local/com.novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1: not found
[warn] some of the dependencies were not recompiled properly, so classloader is not avaialable
[info] Updating {file:/home/johndoe/projects/myproject/}myproject...
[warn]  module not found: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1                              
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/johndoe/projects/lib/play/repository/local/com.novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.1/salat_2.10-1.9.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.1: not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Since I'm getting the feeling you are trying to mix some Scala library compiled against Scala 2.10 with some other library compiled against Scala 2.9, **don't do this!** Really, if you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot, never, ever, mix libraries that are compiled against different Scala major versions (Scala versioning scheme is *era.major.minor*, hence 2.9 and 2.10 have different major version). The reason for this is that Scala only guarantees binary compatiblity across minor releases (shameless plug on binary compatiblity: http://www.slideshare.net/mircodotta/managin-binary-compa)

Comment: Thanks for caution! The question is urgent still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And let me acknowledge my ignorance: the reason was that I failed to run `play` command every time I modified Build.scala. The only thing I tried was `run`, again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Salat 1.9.2-SNAPSHOT is available for 2.10.

Comment: It seems not :(

[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried

[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.2-SNAPSHOT/salat_2.10-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT.pom

[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Releases: tried

[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/novus/salat_2.10/1.9.2-SNAPSHOT/salat_2.10-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT.pom

[warn] ==== public: tried

Comment: Aaand `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest` when trying to insert an object in mongodb. As we can see this plugin uses ClassManifests that are removed from scala 2.10.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, I am getting the same ClassManifest error.